# Написание сайта с ракурса эффективности

Tags: jquery, joomla

Всем привет!

Вкратце в связи с чем вопрос. Заинтересовался написанием сайтов. И по сути на данный момент самоучка. Знаний никаких не было до этого... HTML - языком программирования считал))).

Поэтому интересует несколько глобальный вопрос. Последовательность действий при создании сайта "с нуля" и оценки эффективности его работы.

Исходные условия: предположим решил написать небольшой персональный сайт. Запланированный функционал - инфа о персоне, блог, новости, выкладка фото и видео материалов. Набросал свой дизайн. Среди наиболее сложных элементов - слайдер фоток на jQuery и возможно меню и организация работы фото и видео галлереи. Затем данный шаблон хотел бы прикрутить к какой-н. CMS (пока остановил взор на Joomla). Слайдер почти написал в виде собственого плагина.

Почему такой сложный путь? А не взять подходящий шаблон и сразу сделать всё в CMS с помощью доп. модулей? - Хочу просто набраться опыта.

Прошу поделиться своим опытом. Опишите кратко как проделать данную работу новичку над таким может и простеньким проектом эффективно, с помощью каких средств и как оценить эффективность работы сайта (хотя понятное дело - нет предела совершенству)...
Или, как правило, всё делается лишь бы изначально работало... а потом уже вновь перерабатывается, как должно быть сделано эффективно?

Благодарю всех за ответы!!!

Comment: Буквально сегодня, коллега @stck, приводил [одну статейку](http://css-live.ru/faq/put-verstalshhika.html), отвечая на вопрос. Думаю, что пригодится и вам

Comment: Благодарю за ссылочку.

Comment: @MadMonkey, вопрос будет закрыт, когда будет определён ответ и у вопроса нажмите "закрыть", а не меняйте название, а то путает:)

Comment: [@stck](http://hashcode.ru/users/2092/stck), спасибо за объяснения. Думал тут так заведено. Где нажать "закрыть" я так и не нашёл... со скрипом мне короче первый вопрос дался))))))))

Comment: @MadMonkey,![кнопка закрыть находится прямо под тэгами](http://imageshack.us/a/img7/6060/43194143.png)

Comment: [@stck](http://hashcode.ru/users/2092/stck), извиняюсь, что затюкал...
Причина по ходу в работе сайта... у меня таких кнопочек просто нет, кроме "править".
Ещё раз благодарю за оказанное внимание.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[[@Deonis](/users/4058/deonis)](/users/4058/deonis), спасибо за упоминание, но вроде не моя ссылка:)

---

[[@MadMonkey](/users/9214/madmonkey)](/users/9214/madmonkey), я ... поражён. В общем, мои мысли с самого начала.

Второй и третий абзацы взаимоисключают друг друга. Вы тут подменяете понятие "с нуля", т.е. с создания индексного файла(я создаю индексный :] ), с копированием в директорию фреймворка(или CMS, не суть) - разработке по уже готовому.

> создании сайта "с нуля"
>
> пока остановил взор на Joomla

Вот тут и начинается поток (начинаю писать 3й раз уже) мыслей. Всё дело в не совсем правильном подходе в плане образования(обучения). Когда едешь в машине, нужно знать где тормоз, но при этом можно не знать и не понимать почему протектор резины имеет именно такой вид, а не другой. К чему это я - самообразование, особенно если оно действительно само-, а не пинково-, это очень похвально. Но не стоит стараться охватить всю область сразу.

Начните с ликбеза. Очень часто вижу, как новички в JS сразу бросаются в JQuery, не зная что будет, если сложить `[]` и `{}`. Думаете HTML, CSS можно выучить с помощью [BoilerPlate'ов](http://html5boilerplate.com/) и [Bootstrap'ов](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)? Я ликбез даже спрланировал, и вы конечно можете пропускать пункты, которые не считаете важными или уже знаете:

- [Введение в HTML](http://ru.html.net/tutorials/html/)
- [Введение в CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp)
- [Введение в JS](http://learn.javascript.ru/#book-toc-136)

Это есть та база, без которой лучше пока не задумываться о другом. Ликбезы - сама страшная и нудная вещь, очень скучная, очень тяжёлая. Может быть не сейчас - но вы столкнётесь с референсами по несколько сот страниц, причём довольно унылого материала, тяжелого для восприятия, непонятного, но до некоторого момента. Как показывает мой опыт, когда проект выдвигается в альфа версии всё чаще и чаще начинаешь обращаться к этому референсу в поисках ответов, которые ты даже сам знаешь где находятся.

А теперь наступает шаг серьёзно задуматься - что вы хотите дальше: расти в сторону веб-разработчика, или же веб-программиста(другие варианты отсутствуют в связи с тематикой форума:)).

### Разработчик

Поздравляю, но по-моему мнению ты попал не туда. Здесь тебя ждёт много страданий и мучений, после которых ты вряд ли сможешь работать в команде, а человек стремится быть частью социума, объединяться в сообщества ( ;) ), команды, кружки.

> Термин включает в себя веб-дизайн, программирование для веб на стороне клиента и сервера, а также конфигурирование веб-сервера.(ВИКИ)

Получается, веб-разработчик в одном лице это:

- Информационный архитектор
- Веб-дизайнер
- Веб-мастер
- Верстальщик веб-страниц
- Программист
- Юзабилити-инженер
- Поисковый оптимизатор
- Копирайтер (писатель)
- Тестировщик

Хм, не хило, да? Стараясь ухватиться за всё сразу, начинаем теряться в конечно цели. А учитывая Вашу тягу к перфекционизму (да-да, я подметил) прошу не забывать то, что Вы всё дальше начнёте отдаляться от цели, всё сложнее разобраться во всём этом сумбуре, особенно начиная акцентироваться в мелочах.

Что в принципе у Вас и произошло.

> слайдер фоток на jQuery и возможно меню и организация работы фото и видео галлереи

### Программист

Вот этот парень реально знает чего хочет. Он зачастую умеет больше чем должен, но всё приходит с опытом.
**Не стоит хвататься за всё и сразу - делайте все постепенно.**

Идите, например, по такой логике:

- Что главное для работы сайта? Скрипты/Программы. [Надо учиться программировать](http://helloworld.ru).
- Что нужно для обучения программированию? [Изучить базовые вещи](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).
- Я изучил базовые вещи, я понимаю структуру, я вырос в своих глазах. Дальше? Усилить эти навыки, решать [тупые задачи](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D0%A1%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87+%D0%BF%D0%BE+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E+%25language_name%25&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t), которые развивают логическое мышление, [писать, оценивать, улучшать](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3).
- Вроде готово. Тогда [принципы ООП](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5), о которых столько говорят, учиться представлять [реальные объекты как программные](http://itc.ua/articles/oop_i_uml_korotko_i_bez_mifov_7431/)
- Научиться пользоваться [паттернами проектирования](http://citforum.ru/SE/project/pattern/), читать чужой код, смотреть в нём подход других людей к смежной проблеме.
- Разработка собственных...

А потом уже дизайны, шмодизайны, адаптивная вёрстка и прочие прелести жизни. Научиться верстать после программирования - 2 пальца ..., научиться программировать после вёрстки на серьёзном уровне - тут я бы подумал - надо ли мне оно.

---

Я пишу отходя от вопроса, потому что проделать эффективно **нельзя просто**, эффективность приходит **постепенно** по мере **обучения**. Учитесь, развивайтесь стремитесь к идеалу. Бесчисленным количеством попыток вы придёте к приемлимому результату. Тут как в бодибилдинге - тягая 200кг штангу на первом занятии - кроме шишек и растяжений - ничего не добьёшься. А качки будут сидеть в стороне и ухмыляться на то, как ещё один новичок пытается за день стать Шварцем. Не бывает так. Чисто физически

---

**P.S.** Извините, коротко не получилось.

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ на немного скомканный вопрос)

Comment: @stck, Пожалуйста:) Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).